# Javascript regex match not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following Javascript regexp:

```
 var regex = '/^' + name + '/'; 
 var s ='';
 s = this.innerHTML.toString().toLowerCase().match(regex);
    if (s != null){
         //do stuff
    }
```

This regex does not work as expected, `s` never gets set (`s = null` always)
Any ideas?

Comment: what is `this` referring here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var regex = new RegExp("^" + name);
```

Maybe this fixes the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Since your pattern is dynamically generated through string concatenation, you need to create a RegExp object:

```
var regex = new RegExp('^' + name + ');
```

Comment: ... the two things this answer says are false ... the match function also takes a string, and the pattern is not dynamically evaluated, even with a RegExp

Comment: Good to know about the match function. By dynamic, I meant that the pattern required a string concatenation, as opposed to a hard-coded value. The regex object will need to be recreated each time `name` is updated

Answer (score 1):

You need to use RegExp object when you want to concatenate the query string. So in your case the `/` are part of the query.

```
 var regex = new RegExp('^' + name);
 var s = '';
 s = this.innerHTML.toString().toLowerCase().match(regex);
 if (s != null) {
   //do stuff
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lebolo/CdsTv/) to allow you to test various regex aspects.

The problem is that the formatting of `var regex` is incorrect. Remove the `/`es:

```
// Test code
var name = "foobar";
//var test = "foobar at the start of a sentence";
var test = "a sentence where foobar isn't at the start";

//var regex = '/^' + name + '/'; // Wrong format
var regex = '^' + name; // correct format
var s = '';
//s = this.innerHTML.toString().toLowerCase().match(regex);
s = test.toString().toLowerCase().match(regex);
if (s != null) {
    //do stuff
    alert("works");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to create a regular expression:

1) Using the literal form

```
var re = /\w+/;
```

2) Using object creation form

```
var re = new RegExp("\\w+");
```

Typically you will want the literal form. In your case were you are creating it from a string you must use the object creation form.

```
var re = new RegExp("^" + name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just removing the slashes works.

```
pattern = function(name){"^"+name;}

(name + "whatever").match(pattern(name)); // not null
("whatEver..NotName").match(pattern(name)); // null
```